# A form that is never valid - Symfony2

Tags: php, symfony

I have a class Products which I use for a form and for the database - it has 3 date fields with this or similar:

```php
/**
 * @ORM\Column(name="`date`", type="date")
 * @Assert\NotBlank()
 * @Assert\Type("\Date")
 */
```

It has also 3-4 other fields which has only `NotBlank()`, one without any constraints and a field which is used to save the category of the product (category is another class and table in the database). It looks like this:

```php
/**
 * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Categories")
 * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="categories_id", referencedColumnName="id")
 **/
private $categories;
```

Here is my function:

```php
public function addAction($id, Request $request)
{
    $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getEntityManager(); 
    $products = new Products();
    $products_form = $this->createForm(new ProductsType(), $products);  
    $category = $em->getRepository('AcmeMyBundle:Categories')->find($id);

    if($request->getMethod() == 'POST')
    {
        $products_form->bindRequest($request);

        if($products_form->isValid()) 
        {
            $products->setDomains($category); 
            $em->persist($products);
            $em->flush();
        }
```

At the end it redirects. The problem is that even when I add correct values in the form it says that it is not valid. To add a date a simply write a string like this '2012-08-09' in the form.

When I comment

```
if($products_form->isValid())
```

Everything works fine.

Any suggestions? Please help!

**EDIT:**

Here is the Products class:

```php
/**
 * @ORM\Entity
 * @ORM\Table(name="products")
 */
class Products
{
/**
 * @ORM\Id
 * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
 * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
 */
protected $id;

/**
 * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Categories")
 * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="categories_id", referencedColumnName="id")
 **/
private $categories;

/**
 * @ORM\Column(name="`date`", type="date")
 * @Assert\NotBlank()
 * @Assert\Type("\Date")
 */
protected $date;

/**
 * @ORM\Column(name="`from`", type="date")
 * @Assert\NotBlank()
 * @Assert\Type("\Date")   
 */
protected $from;

/**
 * @ORM\Column(name="`to`", type="date")
 * @Assert\NotBlank()
 * @Assert\Type("\Date")
 */
protected $to;

/**
 * @ORM\Column(type="decimal", scale=2)
 * @Assert\NotBlank()
 */
protected $price;

/**
 * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=5)
 * @Assert\NotBlank()
 */
protected $currency;

/**
 * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=50)
 * @Assert\NotBlank()
 */
protected $paymentid;

/**
 * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=100, nullable=true)
 */
protected $notes;
```

And here I create the form:

```php
class ProductsType extends AbstractType
{
public function buildForm(FormBuilder $builder, array $options)
{
    $builder->add('date', 'date', array(
        'widget' => 'single_text', 
        'format' => 'yyyy-MM-dd'));

    $builder->add('from', 'date', array(
        'widget' => 'single_text', 
        'format' => 'yyyy-MM-dd'));

    $builder->add('to', 'date', array(
        'widget' => 'single_text', 
        'format' => 'yyyy-MM-dd'));

    $builder->add('price', 'text');

    $builder->add('currency', 'choice', array(
        'choices' => array(
            'empty_value'=>'--- Choose ---', 'USD'=>'USD', 'HKD'=>'HKD', 'EUR'=>'EUR', 'BGN'=>'BGN')));

    $builder->add('paymentid', 'text');

    $builder->add('notes', 'text', array(
        'required'  => false));
}

public function getName()
{
    return 'payments';
}
```

Comment: I posted the Products class and the class where I create the form :)

Comment: Ok, i'll edit my answer then :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think in your form ,make sure that csrf token is there.

Add the following code at the below of the form widget inside the  tag.

```
{{ form_widget(form._token) }}
```

Hope this helps you.

Comment: Bravo! +1 Forgot to thing about the dam token :)

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if this is the problem but you have a typo:

```
$productss_form->bindRequest($request);
```

should be

```
$products_form->bindRequest($request);
```

Comment: Mm no :( It's a spelling mistake just here, in the code it's ok. I will edit it here.

Comment: When you post code in stack overflow, copy it from your file and paste it here, don´t retype it, that way you make sure your code is posted without mistakes

Answer (score 1):

Without seeing the form code i can say:

- That `@Assert\Type("\Date")` should be `@Assert\Date`
- Ensure that `data_class` option is settend in your `ProductsType` class

Comment: How to ensure that data_class option is settend in my ProductsType class :(

Comment: So you should not mark the answer as accepter :) Your getDefaultOptions(array $options) method should return data_class!